# Как изменить цвет определённого элемента BottomNavigationView используя ColorStateList?

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

Пытаюсь к используемым по умолчанию в BottomNavigationView двум цветам (для двух состояний пунктов меню) добавить третье состояние и третий цвет. Для этого в папке drawable создал файл "bottom_nav_colors.xml" с селекторами:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked = "true"  
        android:color = "@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true"  
        android:color = "@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:color = "@color/colorGray" />
</selector >
```

В файле разметки "activity_main.xml" указал так:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_colors"/>
```

Однако не могу разобраться, каким методом класса "BottomNavigationView" из класса "MainActivity.java" (наследуется от класса "MvpAppCompatActivity") активировать для нужного мне элемента меню состояние "activated" (или любое другое из списка: "accelerated", "active" и т.д.).

Ну или если так сделать нельзя, то как можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, в "BottomNavigationView" этот фокус не получится. Зато если использовать его наследника [отсюда](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx), то всё делается достаточно легко:

```
if (ServiceApp.getCartsGoodsNumber() > 0) {

    bnve.getBottomNavigationItemView(i).setIconTintList(
        ContextCompat.getColorStateList(
            bnve.getContext(),
            color.bottom_select_nav_colors));
    addBadgeAt(bnve, i, ServiceApp.getCartsGoodsNumber());

} else {

    bnve.getBottomNavigationItemView(i).setIconTintList(null);

    if (mNavigation_20Badge != null) mNavigation_20Badge.hide(true);
}
```

Здесь bnve эеземпляр класса ["BottomNavigationViewExe"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx/master/widget/src/main/java/com/ittianyu/bottomnavigationviewex/BottomNavigationViewEx.java), а метод addBadgeAt() выглядит так:

```
private void addBadgeAt(BottomNavigationViewEx bnve, 
                        final int position, final int number) {
    // add badge
    mNavigation_20Badge = new QBadgeView(bnve.getContext())
            .setBadgeNumber(number).setGravityOffset(12, 2, true)
            .bindTarget(bnve.getBottomNavigationItemView(position));
}
```

Этот метод позволяет добавить к иконке бэйджик:

[image: Панель навигации на основе "BottomNavigationViewExe"]